# Form Not Posting Data back to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post a form using ASP.Net MVC (C#). When the form is posted, none of the data arrives at the controller. The viewmodel remains in it's initialised state.

You can see below that the form data that is posted (copied from Chrome Developers tools) but when it hits the controller, there's nothing there:

```
Triage.ClaimNumber:Test-001
Triage.PropertyAgeId:1
Triage.RoomNumber:1
Triage.Rooms[0].RoomHeight:3
Triage.Rooms[0].RoomWidth:3
Triage.Rooms[0].RoomLength:4
Triage.Rooms[0].CleaningRequired:False
Triage.Rooms[0].DryingRequired:False
Triage.Rooms[0].CeilingDamaged:True
Triage.Rooms[0].WallsDamaged:False
Triage.Rooms[0].FloorDamaged:False
Triage.Rooms[0].KitchenDamaged:False
Triage.Rooms[0].BathroomDamaged:False
Triage.Rooms[0].Ceiling.CeilingTypeId:66
Triage.Rooms[0].Ceiling.AmountDamaged:0.10
Triage.Rooms[0].Ceiling.Papered:False
```

[image: Example]

The name conventions are right for the model binding to take automatically, can anyone help me with why the data isn't being posted?

Here's samples of the viewmodels:

**Ceiling View Model**

```
public class TriageCeilingViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Ceiling type")]
    public int CeilingTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the amount of damage to the ceiling")]
    [DisplayName("% Amount damaged")]
    public decimal AmountDamaged { get; set; }

......
}
```

**Triage View Model**

```
public class TriageRoomViewModel
{
    private Repository _data = new Repository();

    public List<CeilingTypeList> CeilingTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return _data.GetCeilingTypes();
        }
    }

    [Required()]
    [DisplayName("Height (m)")]
    public decimal RoomHeight { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Is the ceiling damaged?")]
    [DisplayName("Ceiling damaged?")]
    public bool CeilingDamaged { get; set; }


    public TriageCeilingViewModel Ceiling = new TriageCeilingViewModel();

    ........
}
```

**Index View Model**

```
public class TriageViewModel
{
    private readonly Repository _data = new Repository();

    public List<PropertyAgeList> PropertyAges
    {
        get
        {
            return _data.GetPropertyAges();
        }
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the claim number")]
    [StringLength(12, ErrorMessage = "The claim number must be 12 digits or less")]
    [DisplayName("Claim Number")]
    public string ClaimNumber { get; set; }

    public List<TriageRoomViewModel> Rooms = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(i => new TriageRoomViewModel()).ToList();

    ........
}
```

**TriageIndexViewModel**

```
public class TriageIndexViewModel
{
     public TriageViewModel = new TriageViewModel();
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        ViewBag.RoomNumber = i;
        @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Triage.Rooms[i])
    }
}
```

**TriageRoomViewModel.cshtml**

```
@model BuildingsTriage.TriageRoomViewModel

<div class="panel-body">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 form-group @(ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField(Html.IdFor(m=>m.RoomHeight).ToString()) ? null : "has-error")">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RoomHeight, new { @class="room" + i + " control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.RoomHeight, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class="room" + i + " form-control", type = "text" }, })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RoomHeight)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 form-group @(ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField(Html.IdFor(m=>m.RoomWidth).ToString()) ? null : "has-error")">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RoomWidth, new { @class="room" + i + " control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.RoomWidth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class="room" + i + " form-control", type = "text" }, })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RoomWidth)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 form-group @(ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField(Html.IdFor(m=>m.RoomLength).ToString()) ? null : "has-error")">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RoomLength, new { @class="room" + i + " control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.RoomLength, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class="room" + i + " form-control", type = "text" }, })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RoomLength)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the required code, so that we can understand better.

Comment: @SudiptaMaiti I've added samples of the view models thanks.

Comment: I believe you are posting the form directly, instead of ajax. Verify  dom element id(s) ('view page source' of the browser) - it should match with model properties. You can also share your view code (partially).

Comment: Could you show the viewmodel you're posting? It's likely an issue with the TriageIndexViewModel, not the sub-models.

Comment: Post your controller code. That's the most important thing.

Comment: @SudiptaMaiti The form is posted directly and the ids are all in order.

Comment: @Gareth...Can you show the Razor also?

Comment: @ThomasBoby I've posted a sample, nothing special.

Comment: @ataravati The `HttpGet` action is literally `TriageIndexViewModel = new TriageIndexViewModel();` followed by returning `View(vm)`.

Comment: @user2946329 Have updated with razor views.

Comment: In addition to the fact you have fields, not properties (so the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot set the properties) as noted in the answers, your view should be just `@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Triage.Rooms)` i.e. no loop - the `EditorFor()` method accepts `IEnumerable<T>` and generates the html for each itsm in the collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Fields not Properties. As `TriageIndexViewModel` is not a Property, nothing lower down will bind correctly.

You need to change all your fields to properties, and move their initialization into a zero-parameter constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried changing all of the fields to properties as suggested and no data is still being posted back.

Answer (score 0):

Your index post method accepts a TriageIndexViewModel. You haven't defined this in the view models above. 
Could this even be the problem? You're controller is expecting this view model but you're passing another one in on the form?

Comment: Sorry, have updated the question with the missing view model. The model posted back to the controller is defo `TriageIndexViewModel`.

Comment: Pretty sure your problem is this line: public List<TriageRoomViewModel> Rooms = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(i => new TriageRoomViewModel()).ToList(); You don't have a "setter" like your other properties. It is always being instantiated as a list of 4 empty Rooms. Give it a normal get and set, and create the list on the controller in the Get Index method, or on the view model constructor.